# How to truncate backup paths in rsnapshot

Tags: rsnapshot

I'm not sure if the heading is really coorect. I have a line in my rsnapshot.conf

```
backup  root@123.123.123.123:/mnt/rsnapshot/      srv01/
```

So rsnapshot creates a directors `RSNAPSHOT_ROOT/daily.0/srv01/mnt/rsnapshot` and puts the backed-up files there. For me, the `/mnt/rsnapshot` part is unnecessary; I'd rather have my backed-up files directly in `RSNAPSHOT_ROOT/daily.0/srv01/`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`rsnapshot` uses the `--relative` flag of `rsync` to preserve pathname information. In most cases, you probably do want to keep (at least some of) that information, especially when backing up local directories. However, in your case, you really don't need to keep the leading path prefix.

With reasonably recent versions of `rsync` (v.2.6.7+), you can explicitly control the portion of the pathname prefix that `--relative` saves by inserting a `./` at the desired cut-point. The `./` does not effectively change the pathname, but it does tell `rsync` that you want `--relative` to only keep the part of the pathname that follows the `./`. Since you want to cut off the entire pathname, you simply append the `./` onto the end of the source path, like this:

```
backup  root@123.123.123.123:/mnt/rsnapshot/./  srv01/
```

**EDIT**

Okay, so it looks like the `./` trick won't work in this case, since `rsnapshot` strips off the trailing `/`. Instead, you should be able to disable the `--relative` option on a per-backup-point basis, by adding a fourth column to your `backup` line, like this:

```
backup  root@123.123.123.123:/mnt/rsnapshot/  srv01/  +rsync_long_args=--no-relative
```

The `+rsync_long_args` tells `rsnapshot` to append to its existing `rsync_long_args` option, for the current backup-point only. By appending `--no-relative` to `rsync_long_args`, you achieve the desired effect of turning off `--relative`.

Comment: in theory, and according to the manpage, this should work, but it doesn't -- I still have the `/mnt/rsnapshot` in my backups. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `rsnapshot` "sanitizes" the source pathname before passing it to `rsync`, stripping off the extra `./`. Check the log file `/var/log/rsnapshot.log`, it should show you exactly what `rsync` commands it is issuing.

Comment: rsnapshot seems to cut off the trailing `/`, so that it rsync with the path `root@123.123.123.123:/mnt/rsnapshot/.` Is there anything I can do without disabling `--relative`?

Comment: @andreas-h: Check out the EDIT. I hope this solves it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Steven's first suggestion to use `./` does actually work with rsnapshot, you just have to put it twice:

```
backup  root@123.123.123.123:/mnt/rsnapshot/././  srv01/
```

Rsnapshot will strip the last slash of, but the first dot works for rsync.

Comment: you still need ` +rsync_long_args=--no-relative` don't you?

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is actually controlled by rsync's `--relative` flag. Quoting [the rsync manual](https://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html):

> **-R, --relative**
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on
>   the command line are sent to the server rather than just the last
>   parts of the filenames. This is particularly useful when you want to
>   send several different directories at the same time. For example, if
>   you used this command:
>
> ```
> rsync -av /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
> ```
>
> ... this would create a file named baz.c in /tmp/ on the remote
>   machine. If instead you used
>
> ```
> rsync -avR /foo/bar/baz.c remote:/tmp/
> ```
>
> then a file named /tmp/foo/bar/baz.c would be created on the remote
>   machine, preserving its full path. These extra path elements are
>   called "implied directories" (i.e. the "foo" and the "foo/bar"
>   directories in the above example). [...]

So, in your `rsnapshot.conf` find the line that starts with `rsync_long_args`. By default, `--delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded` should be present. Removing the `--relative` option, should lead to the desired results.